# Sanitize user input if input has html

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sanitization

I have user input that will contain html that I need to sanitize. Currently I am using:

```
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/', '', $data);
```

for the other inputs (w/o html). I am allowing underscores and hyphens because they are twitter usernames for a user's profile. Any ideas for sanitizing input with html markup inside it?

Answer (score 1):

HTML sanitization by other means its protection the site from XSS attacks. According to [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) cleaning HTML depends on which how you print the user data, for example: the following table shows different scenarios of which different protection mechanisms will be applied:

[image]

php strip_tags function can be used for some cases while, its not safe for all kind of malicious code. I recommend to follow OWASP.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. Also, we can assume from the question that this will be displayed as-is on a web page in the HTML/HTML-Body context that OWASP is showing above.